# Problems with NSTabView autolayout (view based NSTableViews inside tabs)

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

I have an NSTabView which has 5 tabs. Each tab contains an NSTableView (which, as default, is nested in NSScrollView). This is all loaded from a xib file with autolayout turned on. I'd like each table to fully occupy it's respective tab. Using autolayout I select each tab and carefully setup the NSScrollView so that it snaps its top, bottom, lead, and trailing edges to superview. After I do this for the 5 tabs, I'll resize the xib to give it a test. When I cycle back through the tabs, some stay snapped to the superview and some do not. There appears to be some sort of order to this but it is beyond what I can explain.

What's really frustrating is that sometime this will run okay, and sometimes it will crash because of unsatifyable constraints. For now I am using springs/struts but I like autolayout and would like to get it working.

I am afraid that it is the nesting of the tables inside scroll views which is causing the issues.

If you lay this out your own nib, you should be able to reproduce it.

I am hopeful that this can be solved by adding NSLayoutConstraints at runtime, if OSX is anything like iOS's autolayout. Using IB you cannot assing constraints to anythign other than super and sibling (no cousins). This can be done at runtime.

I am hoping someone out there has encountered this issue and has a solution.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simplifying your system with only one tab to find out what constraint is incorrect and breaking the system when running the application? Adding the constraint error message here will enable people to help you better

Answer (score 0):

Why do the constraints in the layout show a fixed constant instead of auto?  Could that be it?

You mentioned cousin constraints, I believe you can add in the in IB if you select two views in the document outline on the left hand side and then add a constraint.  I'm unable to pick any two views in IB if I'm using the main window but I can do it in the document outline.

Lastly, you mention it will run okay sometimes but not others - and if that's the case it sounds like something else is adding constraints.  Instruments should have a template for tracing constraints, if you can reproduce it you may get a clue to what is introducing the incompatible constraint.

Comment: I'll address your paragraphs by numbers. 1.) The image shows springs and struts simply because I had switched over to that model for the time being. I thought the picture would still give off useful information. 2.) I'll give that a try, thanks. 3.) It runs okay sometimes and not others because of how the OS decides to position and size the main window. This is definitely the cause; It puts the window in a state that makes the NSLayoutConstraints grumpy. 

I've actually been able to use springs and struts for this nib (I'm pleased to see that you can disable autolayout on OSX apps)